# Некорректное поведение при динамической компоновке

Tags: c, библиотеки, компоновщик

Имеются два файла:
 `main.c` - вызывает функцию `read` из динамической библиотеки `mylib.dll`, которая компилируется из `mylib.c`. Используется метод динамической компоновки.

Собственно, "проект":

`main.c`:

```
__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl read(void);

int main(void)
{
    read();

    return 0;
}
```

библиотека `mylib.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl read(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

Сборка:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -c mylib.c
gcc -shared mylib.o -Wl,--subsystem,windows -o mylib.dll
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -c main.c
gcc main.o -L. -lmylib -o main.exe
```

(компилятор gcc, WIN10 + MSYS64)

В итоге запускаю исполняемый файл `main.exe` и ничего не происходит. Ожидаемое приветствие не отобразилось.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В main.c должно быть dllimport.

Comment: @VladD, да, исправил опечатку. Проблема остается актуальной.

Comment: А если для тестов переименовать функцию в `read1`?

Comment: Работает.  Тогда почему название `read` некорректно?

Comment: Думаю, происходит конфликт с уже существующей функцией `read`. Это ж C, namespace'ов нет. // Напишу ответ, чтобы вопрос не оставался без ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что проблема в имени функции. В C перегруженных функций нет, и поскольку в стандартной библиотеке уже существует функция `read`, то компилятор/компоновщик использует её.

Переименуйте вашу функцию, должно заработать.